# pgfplots animate, with axes fixed

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, animate

I have the following MWE for two plots that should show one after another:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\beging{frame}[fragile]
\begin{animateinline}{8}
        \multiframe{8}{ie=2+1,iw=2+1}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}
                \addplot plot[
                    mark=e, red,
                    x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1<=\ie ? #1 : "nan"}}
                ] 
                coordinates {
                    (2,4)
                    (3,5)
                    (4,6)
                    (5,7)
                };
                \addplot plot[mark=w,blue,x filter/.code={\pgfmathparse{#1<=\iw ? #1 : "nan"}}]
                coordinates {
                    (2,2)
                    (3,6)
                    (4,7)
                    (5,8)
                };
            \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
    \end{animateinline}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This works well, except that the axes keep changing. How to fix the axes beforehand?

Comment: Use `axis` options `xmin=...`, `xmax=..`, `ymin=...`, `ymax=...`.

Comment: I get a lot of `Package PGF Math Error: Could not parse input '@@str@@:nan' as a floating poi 1Y2.0e0] : "nan"'). }` errors when trying to compile your code (even after fixing the typos)